# Best way to check if mutation observer passes certain conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mutation-observers

I have implemented a mutation observer that watches for mutations to the page load. I am specifically looking for the point at which a particular element is loaded/exists. I can specify it by its classname which for sake of example is `foo`.

When `foo` is found in the list of mutated objects, I wish to call a function.

Currently, I have the following:

```
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    if (!mutation.addedNodes || mutation.addedNodes[0].className === undefined || mutation.addedNodes[0].className !== 'foo') {
      return;
    } else {
      console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0].className + ' loaded!');
    }
  });
```

This technically works: when it passes the three conditions I do indeed see the console log.

However, in cases where `mutation.addedNodes[0]` does not have any `className` data it provides the error

> Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

I do understand why this is happening; sometimes `mutations` has no `addedNodes[0]` so is indeed undefined. What I am not sure about is the best way to fire the console log (later will be my function) only when those above tests are passed.

I am still learning ES6, and I expect there is something that can help me here but I'm just struggling to find the best way.

Comment: Include one more condition `!mutation.addedNodes || !mutation.addedNodes[0] || ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. During page load each reported node may be a container with dozens or hundreds of nested nodes so you need to enumerate all `addedNodes` and check each one's tree.
2. Some of the reported mutation records may be about removed nodes (for example, by the page script) so `addedNodes` will be an empty array.
3. Some of the added nodes will be comments or text nodes so you need to skip those.

```
const matching = [];
for (const {addedNodes} of mutations) {
  for (const node of addedNodes) {
    if (node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      continue;
    }
    if (node.classList.contains(className)) {
      matching.push(node);
    }
    if (node.children[0]) {
      matching.push(...node.getElementsByClassName(className));
    }
  }
}
if (matching.length) console.log(matching);
```